# RDP users can't access website even though it's mapped to the intranet zone and enhanced security is off

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, ms-access-2003, group-policy

I have a MS access 2003 database which includes a webbrowser control to allow users to visit one specific website. This MS access database is accessed via RDP on Windows Server 2008 R2. I should also mention that this access mdb is set up as their startup program via batch file on their user account, so this is all they are allowed to do on the server. The webbrowser control is completely locked down with no menus so they can only go to this website.

At first, we were getting 'navigation cancelled' and at the time it was IE10. I used gpedit.exe to modify administrative templates to map the site to the intranet zone. Also in the intranet zone I allow active scripting. This didn't make it work. I then turned off IE advanced security in server manager and added a registry setting to map the site to the intranet zone as well when the group policy didn't do the trick. Strangely, I had to log on as each user without the start up program checked so windows could do it's settings thing at the first logon. Then, I put the startup program back. Annoying yes, but this finally allowed access to the website...for awhile.

Last week, users started reporting the site is showing navigation cancelled again. I employed my trusty and annoying workaround: unchecking the startup program from the affected user account, logged on as them once, logged off, checked the startup program again, logged back on as them and then accessed the site through our access mdb form.

It worked, but I wondered what had changed. I took a look and IE had updated to IE11 automatically at some point so I attributed it to that. Yesterday, that same user reported that they can't open PDFs from that site. They are getting 'content blocked' as if IE enhanced security was turned on. I verified that it is not turned on, under server manager and I also looked at IsInstalled registry setting under IEHardenUser and IEHardenAdmin and they are all set to 0.

So...right now with all the group policies in place to map the site to an intranet zone, IEESC turned off and registry settings to map the site to an intranet zone - I STILL have users that get navigation cancelled and users that can't click links on that site and users that can't open a PDF on that site.

Does anyone have any ideas for me? And please don't say to stop using MS Access with a webbrowser control over RDP. I'm working on it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, which I am not all that excited about is this:

1. Log onto the affected server, via RDP using an administrator-level account.
2. Open the affected user's account in Server Manager and click the 'Environment' tab.
3. Un-check the startup program and click 'Apply' leave this window open.
4. Open another RDP session as the affected user.
5. Open Internet Explorer and go to tools > internet options (or the gear symbol and internet options.)
6. On the Advanced tab click Reset, check off Delete personal settings, click Reset button, and finally close IE.
7. Log off.
8. Go back to the RDP window you had open as the administrator.
9. Check the box so they will get MotorBase as their startup program once again.
10. Click OK.
11. Log back onto the server in anther RDP window as that user again.
12. Test to make sure the navigation isn't cancelled.